# Qt Pb with QAction, QToolBar, QToolButton

Tags: qt, button, action, toolbar

I got a problem here.

I'm building a Qt app that uses slidingStackedWidgets in order to slide from one page to another one.

I have 2 toolBars, a topToolBar and a bottomToolBar that do not slide when the central widget moves.

So I have declared a QAction in my mainWindow.h

```
 QAction *backToMainVert;
```

And in my mainWindow.cpp, when I call the second view by clicking a button, I call a slideInAdd() method that goes like this:

```
slidingStacked->slideInIdx(1); //this takes me back to my second page
backToMainVert = this->topToolBar->addWidget(backBarButton); 
//this adds a backButton to the topToolBar
```

Now the backBarButton is connected to a slideToMain() method which, when triggered takes me back to my first page and removes the backBarButton from the topToolBar

```
    this->topToolBar->removeAction(backToMainVert);
    slidingStacked->slideInIdx(0);
```

The first time I switch to the second page, no problem, my button is created and displayed on my topToolBar.

When I click the backBarButton, it goes back to the first page.

BUT the second time I want to return from the first page to the second page, the backBarButton never appears.

Uh, maybe this can help, here is the way I instantiate my backBarButton :

```
 backBarButton = new QToolButton(this);
 backBarButton->setText("Retour");
 backBarButton->setFixedSize(80,30);
 backBarButton->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/ToolBarButton.png);"
                             "background-repeat: no-repeat;"
                             "background-position: center center;"
                             "border:0;"
                             "color : white;"
                             "font-family: System;"
                             "font-style: bold;"
                             "font-size: 9pt;"
                             "color : white;");
```

Any idea what I'm missing here please ?

Thanks in advance, I'm stuck.

Miky Mike

---

Hello World,

Could someone suggest another way of achieving a ToolBar ?
I wish I could find by myself but the debugger inside Qt
doesn't give me much detail. It doesn't even stop on my breakpoint.
Where should I start ?

Thanks for your help.

Mike

---

Ok guys,

Seems that the only way to go is to add a QAction to the topToolBar in the slideInAdd() method.

```
  void MainWindow::slideInAdd(){

     slidingStacked->setVerticalMode(true);
     slidingStacked->slideInIdx(1);
     backAction = new QAction(QIcon(":/ToolBarButton.png"), tr("&Retour"), this);
     topToolBar->addAction(backAction);
     connect(this->backAction,SIGNAL(triggered()),this, SLOT(slideInMainVert()));
 }
```

and this in the slideInMainVert() method :

```
    this->topToolBar->removeAction(backAction);
```

It's working that way but the problem is that I can't figure out how to customize the QToolButton that appears in the topToolBar. I would like it to be bigger  than the default size (say...100x30) with some text on it (just like a button actually).

Could you help me please ?

Thanks a lot...

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found a way !!!

Ready ?

1) So first we create a widget that will contain the layout that will hold the buttons :

```
QWidget * toolBarContainerWidget = new QWidget(this);
```

2) then we create the layout that will contain the buttons

```
QHBoxLayout *toolBarLayout = new QHBoxLayout(toolBarContainerWidget);
```

3) then we create the backButton :

```
QPushButton *testButton = new QPushButton("Go Back !",toolBarContainerWidget);
testButton->setFixedSize(80,20);
testButton->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/ToolBarButton.png);"
                          "background-repeat: no-repeat;"
                          "background-position: center center;"
                          "border:0;"
                          "color : white;"
                          "font-family: System;"
                          "font-style: bold;"
                          "font-size: 9pt;"
                          "color : white;");
```

4) We now add our testButton to our toolBarLayout :

```
toolBarLayout->addWidget(testButton);
```

5) We set the layout as the toolBarContainerWidget : (and here the brain begins to sweat...;-))

```
toolBarContainerWidget->setLayout(toolBarLayout);
```

6) We add this widget to our toolbar :

```
topToolBar->addWidget(toolBarContainerWidget);
```

7) We connect the Button to the slideInMainVert() method :

```
QObject::connect(testButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(slideInMainVert()));
```

8) When we slide back to the first page, we use :

```
topToolBar->clear();
```

which clears up the toolBar...

Uh, well, I have to admit that it's a bit complicated but I haven't been able to find a better way.
If you guys have any suggestion, please let me know...

Hope this can help anyway...

Miky Mike